# Determining the first memory address

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, armv8

I'm working on a project to extract a key from memory. So i want to know the first memory address. For that i have samsung galaxy S7 with ARM processor ARMv8-A.I have taken a look at its kernel and i found following:

```
#include "exynos8890.dtsi"

{
memory@80000000 {
    device_type = "memory";

    reg = <0x0 0x80000000 0x80000000>;
};
memory@880000000 {
    device_type = "memory";

    reg = <0x00000008 0x80000000 0x80000000>;
};
```

Does indicate the address 0x80000000 to the first memory address?

Comment: What "**first memory address**" is? Please, elaborate that in the question post.

Comment: Looks like author is asking about lowest ram physical address. If so you better refer soc documentation,  memory map concretely.

Comment: Once the Linux kernel enables the MMU to use virtual memory, knowing the *"first memory address"* is probably not as useful as you think it is.